# Interactive View Controller Transition - Weird behavior (stuck in the transition)

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a custom `pan` gesture to interactively transition to a new `view controller`. The way it works is that I have a button (labeled "Template Editor", see below) on which you can start a `pan` to move the current `view controller` to the right, revealing the new `view controller` next to it (I've recorded my problem, see below).

Everything is working but there is a bug that I don't understand at all:

Sometimes, when I just swipe over the button (triggering a `pan` gesture) then lift my finger again *(touch down -> fast, short swipe to the right -> touch up)* the interactive transition glitches out. It starts to **very slowly** complete the transition and afterwards, I cannot dismiss the presented `view controller`, nor can I present anything on that presented `view controller`.

I have no idea why. Here's my code:

First, the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` class. It's implemented using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and just adds the animation using `transform`:

```
class MovingTransitionAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum Direction {
        case left, right
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    // ========== PROPERTIES ==========
    private var animator: UIViewImplicitlyAnimating?

    var duration = 0.6
    var presenting = true

    var shouldAnimateInteractively: Bool = false

    public var direction: Direction = .left
    private var movingMultiplicator: CGFloat {
        return direction == .left ? -1 : 1
    }
    // ====================

    // MARK: - Initializers
    // ========== INITIALIZERS ==========

    // ====================

    // MARK: - Overrides
    // ========== OVERRIDES ==========

    // ====================


    // MARK: - Functions
    // ========== FUNCTIONS ==========
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let animator = interruptibleAnimator(using: transitionContext)
        animator.startAnimation()
    }

    func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {

        // If the animator already exists, return it (important, see documentation!)
        if let animator = self.animator {
            return animator
        }

        // Otherwise, create the animator

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

        if presenting {
            toView.frame = containerView.frame
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movingMultiplicator * toView.frame.width, y: 0)
        } else {
            toView.frame = containerView.frame
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -movingMultiplicator * toView.frame.width, y: 0)
        }

        containerView.addSubview(toView)

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 0.9, animations: nil)

        animator.addAnimations {
            if self.presenting {
                toView.transform = .identity
                fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.movingMultiplicator * toView.frame.width, y: 0)
            } else {
                toView.transform = .identity
                fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.movingMultiplicator * toView.frame.width, y: 0)
            }
        }

        animator.addCompletion { (position) in
            // Important to set frame above (device rotation will otherwise mess things up)
            toView.transform = .identity
            fromView.transform = .identity

            if !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled {
                self.shouldAnimateInteractively = false
            }

            self.animator = nil
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }

        self.animator = animator
        return animator
    }
    // ====================


}
```

---

Here's the part that adds the interactivity. It's a method that's being called by a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` I added to the button.

```
    public lazy var transitionAnimator: MovingTransitionAnimator = MovingTransitionAnimator()
    public lazy var interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()

    ...

    @objc private func handlePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = pan.translation(in: utilityView)
        var progress = (translation.x / utilityView.frame.width)
        progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))

        switch pan.state {
        case .began:

            // This is a flag that helps me distinguish between when a user taps on the button and when he starts a pan
            transitionAnimator.shouldAnimateInteractively = true

            // Just a dummy view controller that's dismissing as soon as its been presented (the problem occurs with every view controller I use here)
            let vc = UIViewController()
            vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
            vc.transitioningDelegate = self
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
                self.transitionAnimator.shouldAnimateInteractively = false
                vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        case .changed:
            interactionController.update(progress)
        case .cancelled:
            interactionController.cancel()
        case .ended:
            if progress > 0.55 || pan.velocity(in: utilityView).x > 600 
                interactionController.completionSpeed = 0.8
                interactionController.finish()
            } else {
                interactionController.completionSpeed = 0.8
                interactionController.cancel()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

---

I also implemented all the necessary delegate methods:

```
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transitionAnimator.presenting = true
        return transitionAnimator
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transitionAnimator.presenting = false
        return transitionAnimator
    }

    func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        guard let animator = animator as? MovingTransitionAnimator, animator.shouldAnimateInteractively else { return nil }
        return interactionController
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        guard let animator = animator as? MovingTransitionAnimator, animator.shouldAnimateInteractively else { return nil }
        return interactionController
    }
```

---

That's it. There's no more logic behind it (I think; if you need more information, please tell me), but it still has this bug. Here's a recording of the bug. You can't really see my touch but all I'm doing is *touching down -> fast, shortly swiping to the right -> touching up*. And after this really slow transition has finished, I can't dismiss the red `view controller`. It's stuck there:

[image: demonstration]

Here's what's even stranger:

Neither `interactionController.finish()` nor `interactionController.cancel()` is being called when this occurs (at least not from within my `handlePan(_:)`method).

I checked the `view hierarchy` in `Xcode` after this bug occurred and I got this:

[image: view hierarchy]

First, it's seemingly stuck in the transition (everything is still inside `UITransitionView`).

Second, on the left hand side you see the `views` of the first `view controller`(the one I start the transition from). However, on the image there only is the red `view controller` visible, the one that was about to be presented.

Do you have any idea what's going on? I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hours but I can't get get it to work properly. I'd appreciate any help

Thank you!

### EDIT

Okay, I found a way to reproduce it 100% of the time. I also created an isolated project demonstrating the problem (it's a little differently structured because I tried many things but the result is still exactly the same)

Here's the project: https://github.com/d3mueller/InteractiveTransitionDemo2

**How to reproduce the problem:**

Swipe from right to left and then quickly from left to right. This will trigger the bug.

Also, a similar bug will appear, when you swipe from right to left very fast multiple times. Then it will actually run the transition and finish it correctly (but it shouldn't even start because moving from right to left keeps the `progress` at 0.0)

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting:

```
/// Set this to NO in order to start an interruptible transition non
/// interactively. By default this is YES, which is consistent with the behavior
/// before 10.0.
@property (nonatomic) BOOL wantsInteractiveStart NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0);
```

to `NO` on your `interactionController`

Good luck and curious to hear if you figure it out.

Comment: Dang, I forgot about this question. The solution was surprisingly pretty simple. I didn't clean up the views properly. Turns out this messes things up. When I corrected this it started to work perfectly fine in all cases.

Thanks for the answer though :)